# Dropdown list from another field

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have 2 dropdown fields in grocery crud,one is a select items and the other is select units, can i make one field dependent upon the other? Example when i choose an items, the only available options in the unit selection are the units assigned only in that selected item in the database. Thanks.

```
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
        $crud->set_subject('Release Item');
        $crud->set_table('dept_release');
        $crud->set_relation('departments_id','departments','name');
        $crud->set_relation('destination_id','destination','name');
        $query = $this->db->query("select id,name from items where type=0");
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $key => $v) {
                $item_list[$v['id']] = $v['name']; 
            };
             $crud->field_type('item', 'dropdown', $item_list);
        }
        $crud->field_type('users_id', 'hidden', $this->session->userdata('id'));
        $crud->field_type('unit', 'dropdown', array(null => 'Please select a unit'));
        $crud->field_type('sy_id', 'hidden', $this->session->userdata('sy_id'));
        $crud->unset_read();
        $output = $crud->render();
        $this->_unit_output($output,"Units");
```

Comment: Using ajax u can make dependable drop down list

Comment: yes sir i tried to do that, i have successfully inserted option tags inside the select tag but it doesn't work in grocery crud.

Comment: where you have faced problem... explain your problem clearly and share your code.i will try to solve your problem

Comment: thank you, i have edited my post..

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tbl where id=[id]
```

Bind id and put in dropdownlist onchangeevent,
and bind other dropdownlist base on result.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $results = $this->db->query('select distinct tahap_penyusunan from m_penyusunan_proleg proleg order by id_penyusunan_proleg')->result();
                 $employees_multiselect = array();
                 foreach ($results as $result) {
                    $employees_multiselect[$result->tahap_penyusunan] = $result->tahap_penyusunan;
                 }
->field_type('penyusunan', 'dropdown',$employees_multiselect)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to  your answer. Code only answers does not server any purpose to the future readers.

Comment: $results = $this->db->query('this is your query')->result();
                 $employees_multiselect = array();
                 foreach ($results as $result) {
                    $employees_multiselect[$result->fields] = $result->fields;
                 }
->field_type('u selected field', 'dropdown',$employees_multiselect)